# Help with "selected" items on JQuery Menu

Tags: jquery, menu

I am trying to create a simple vertical menu, with submenus. I wanted the selected item to be highlighted as well as if the submenu is selected, for it to stay open.

i am sooo lost :(

please help me figure this out.
this is what i have so far

```
<ul id="menu"> 
 <li><a href="/Source.aspx" > New </a></li>
 <li><a href="#"> New Transaction</a>
 <ul> 
 <li><a href="/Transaction.aspx?id=S">Shipment</a></li> 
 <li><a href="/Transaction.aspx?id=R">Reciept</a></li> 
 <li><a href="/Transaction.aspx?id=DA">Disassemble</a></li> 
 <li><a href="/Transaction.aspx?id=DS">Disposal</a></li> 
 </ul> </li>
 <li><a href="/Source.aspx?id=U">Correction</a></li>
 </ul>
```

here is my js:

```
function initMenu() {
    $("#menu ul").hide();
    $("#menu li a").click(function() {
    $("#menu li").removeClass('selected');
    $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
        $(this).next().slideToggle('normal');
    });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    initMenu();

});
```

"selected" class is supposed to highlight the menu in yellow, right now it just blinks yellow when i click on it and goes away...
the sub menu does not stay open either :(((

Answer (score 2):

I'm wondering, do you intercept the click on the links and do some Ajax loading?
If you're not, it's logic that the selected class disapear, because the page change/reload.

To solve that, you can write a init function that checks the window.location against all your menu hrefs and add the selected class to the match...

tip: use firebug to check the state of your elements (check if a selected class is on your element for example), it will help you to understand...

Answer (score 1):

As @Guillaume86 said, I put the init code posted below in my document.ready function.
I think it should be quite simple to understand it:

`.menu` is the menu links class. The script checks for all menu items if their href attribute is equal to the actual page location and updates all of them with the `selected` or `not_selected` class.

```
$('.menu').each (function(){
    if ($(this).attr('href') == $(location).attr('href'))
        $(this).addClass('selected').removeClass('not_selected');
    else
        $(this).addClass('not_selected').removeClass('selected');
});
```